# EMI UCP Syntax Error

Tags: perl, ucp

I have a perl code that sends a reminder sms via `Net::UCP package`. It worked so far, until now, I started to get negative acknowledgement with 02 reason code. The EMI UCP documentation says, it refers to syntax error, but I don't know why. It worked for like 6 months. Here is the sent string:
`02/00454/O/51/0036204802483/36303444080/////////////////3/8/5469737A74656C7420DC677966656CFC6E6B21200A0A54E16AE96B6F7A7461746A756B2C20686F6779206C656AE17261746920534D5320737A6F6C67E16C746174E173756E6B20746563686E696B6169206F6B6F6B62F36C206D6567737A3F6E696B2E200A4BE9726AFC6B2C206B69656D656C74656E2066696779656C6A656E2061207AE16C6F676A65677965206C656AE1726174E172612E200A0A5469737A74656C657474656C3A200A42C1562050E96E7AFC677969205A7274////1////1139/////04`

And here is what I receive:
`02/00022/R/51/N/02//07`

My question is where is the syntax error in the sent string? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It was the MB parameter that was set to 8. I also noticed that a new message was uploaded that was too long, was longer than 160 characters, so I told the client to change it.